# How to get StringProperty(JavaFX) of label for components that be connected to label by setLabelFor?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a control that implements

```
@Override
public Control setLabel(Label label) {
    label.setLabelFor(this);
    return this;
}


@Override
public Label getLabel() {
    return (Label) this.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.LABELED_BY);
}
```

The Label is not inner content for Control, but reference control near, not inside.

**Before** invoking setLabel I need to bind text from future label on some property. Something like this

someStringProperty.bind(control.labelTextProperty());

How to do this?

I'll try to clarify the issue.

For Label there is property labelForProperty(), therefore It is possible to bind before then setLabelFor method will be invoked. But for Control like TextField I do not find property like textPropertyForConnectedLabel and binding possible only **AFTER** (Label) this.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.LABELED_BY) will be not null.

Comment: And you couldn't look up the correct property name [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textProperty) or in the autocompletion feature of your IDE because???

Comment: Hm.. Maybe I did not exactly put the question.  Before invoking setLabel, getLabel by queryAccessibleAttribute returns null.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you want to perform the binding in `setLabel`? In this case the Label is there as parameter. Or? Personally I do not really understand what question should we answer :)

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the vague wording

Comment: If you are extending `Labeled`, then the [textProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textProperty) stores the text that should be displayed on the `Label`. Was this the question?

Comment: Yes, I know it. But 
questins is not about that at all. I need to get textProperty not for inner Label, but for connected Label for instance to TextField.

Comment: For instance you have a class `A extends Labeled`. You want to assign a `Label` for `A` by calling `setLabel(newLabel)`. But before, you want to bind some properties in `A` to the text of `newLabel` and the question is how to het `newLabel`? Because that one makes no sense. You could update the question with the whole thing you have with some comment what do you want to achieve, or you can wait for others, maybe they can decode what the actual question is :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with help mediator property in control.

```
private StringProperty textLabelProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("");    /**
 *
 */
public Control setLabel(Label label) {
    if (label != null) {
        label.setLabelFor(this);
        textLabelProperty.bind(label.textProperty());
    }
    return this;
}    

public StringProperty labelTextProperty() {
    return textLabelProperty;
}
```